# GraphicsPath AddArc

Tags: c#, winforms, shapes, graphicspath

I'm trying to create a popup bubble with a round rectangle and a thingy at the bottom which  I circled with green on the image bellow:

[image]

But as you have guessed this isn't how i want it to look but instead:

[image]

I figured out how to draw it as i should but in that case when i add border around my path it separates that little triangle and the round rectangle.

Heres the code I'm working with:

```
public static GraphicsPath CreateBubblePath(Rectangle rect, int radius)
{
    GraphicsPath p = new GraphicsPath();
    GraphicsPath p2 = new GraphicsPath();
    p.StartFigure();
    p2.StartFigure();

    int pointHeigt = 3 * radius;

    //Top Left Corner
    p.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 180, 90);

    //Top Edge
    p.AddLine(rect.X + radius, rect.Y, rect.X + rect.Width - radius, rect.Y);

    //Top Right Corner
    p.AddArc(rect.X + rect.Width - 2 * radius, rect.Y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 270, 90);


    //Right Edge
    p.AddLine(rect.X + rect.Width, rect.Y + radius, rect.X + rect.Width, rect.Y + rect.Height - radius - pointHeigt);

    //Bottom Right Corner
    p.AddArc(rect.X + rect.Width - (2 * radius), rect.Y + rect.Height - radius - pointHeigt, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 0, 90);

    //Bottom Edge 1/2
    //METHOD 1
    p.AddLine(rect.X + rect.Width - radius, rect.Y + rect.Height - 2 * radius, rect.X + (rect.Width / 2) + pointHeigt, rect.Y + rect.Height - 2 * radius);

    p.AddArc(rect.X + (rect.Width / 2), rect.Y + rect.Height - 2 * radius , pointHeigt, pointHeigt, 180, 90);
    p.AddArc(rect.X + (rect.Width / 2) - pointHeigt, rect.Y + rect.Height - 2 * radius, pointHeigt, pointHeigt, 270, 90);

    p.AddLine(rect.X + (rect.Width / 2) - pointHeigt, rect.Y + rect.Height - 2 * radius, rect.X + radius, rect.Y + rect.Height - 2 * radius);

    //METHOD 2///////////////////////////////////////
    //p.AddLine(rect.X + rect.Width - radius, rect.Y + rect.Height - 2 * radius, rect.X + radius, rect.Y + rect.Height - 2 * radius);
    //p2.AddArc(rect.X + (rect.Width / 2), rect.Y + rect.Height - 2 * radius, pointHeigt, pointHeigt, 180, 90);
    //p2.AddArc(rect.X + (rect.Width / 2) - pointHeigt, rect.Y + rect.Height - 2 * radius, pointHeigt, pointHeigt, 270, 90);
    //p2.CloseFigure();
    ////////////////////////////////

    //Bottom Left Corner
    p.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Y + rect.Height - radius - pointHeigt, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 90, 90);

    //Left Edge
    p.AddLine(rect.X, rect.Y + rect.Height - radius - pointHeigt, rect.X, rect.Y + radius);

    p.CloseFigure();
    //METHOD 2
    //p.AddPath(p2, true);
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the angles for the arcs are the problem.

I changed them to this:

```
p.AddArc(rect.X + (rect.Width / 2), rect.Y + rect.Height - 2 * radius, pointHeigt, pointHeigt, 270, -90);
p.AddArc(rect.X + (rect.Width / 2) - pointHeigt, rect.Y + rect.Height - 2 * radius, pointHeigt, pointHeigt, 0, -90);
```

And the point on the bottom of the rectangle looks correct now.

Information about arc's angles can be found on the [MSDN page for GraphicsPath.AddArc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142517.aspx), in particular in the Remarks section:

> The arc is traced along the perimeter of the ellipse bounded by the
>   specified rectangle. The starting point of the arc is determined by
>   measuring clockwise from the x-axis of the ellipse (at the 0-degree
>   angle) by the number of degrees in the start angle. The endpoint is
>   similarly located by measuring clockwise from the starting point by
>   the number of degrees in the sweep angle. If the sweep angle is
>   greater than 360 degrees or less than -360 degrees, the arc is swept
>   by exactly 360 degrees or -360 degrees, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I didn't know i can add a negative number to the sweepAngle so knowing that I changed only the following 2 lines:

from

```
p.AddArc(rect.X + (rect.Width / 2), rect.Y + rect.Height - 2 * radius , pointHeigt, pointHeigt, 180, 90);
p.AddArc(rect.X + (rect.Width / 2) - pointHeigt, rect.Y + rect.Height - 2 * radius, pointHeigt, pointHeigt, 270, 90);
```

to:

```
    p.AddArc(rect.X + (rect.Width / 2), rect.Y + rect.Height - 2 * radius , pointHeigt, pointHeigt, 270, -90);
    p.AddArc(rect.X + (rect.Width / 2) - pointHeigt, rect.Y + rect.Height - 2 * radius, pointHeigt, pointHeigt, 0, -90);
```